# GUI Development in Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, embedded-linux

Wondering what are tools out there and which is better to use in GUI development that supports ARM and X86 arch applications.

thanks in advance,
T3nG

Answer (score 9):

The [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) framework should work well for this.

Comment: The link above probably has to be updated to http://qt.digia.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the [Qt Creator IDE](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools). It's has free(LGPL) version.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMoko Freerunner¹ is ARM-based and it runs Qtopia/QtE, GTK and E17 UI stacks. All of them are also supported on x86. GTK is Cairo-based and I heard (*not sure*) that it uses lots of floating-point calculations though, so ARM with GTK might not be very fast.

¹http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Neo_FreeRunner

Answer (score 0):

you can use olso GTK with ruby or C.
much easier than swing

Answer (score 0):

[Maemo](http://maemo.org/) drives Nokia's [internet tablets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N810), which are ARM based.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the power of your device...

The biggest now could be:

- [GNOME Mobile](http://www.gnome.org/mobile/)
- [Qt Embedded](http://www.qtsoftware.com/qt-in-use/target/embedded)

or if you have devices with much less capabilities, you can try simpler things like

- [Microwindows / NanoX](http://www.microwindows.org/)

Of course, if your device is a mobile-like, you can also consider using [Android](http://source.android.com/) ... who knows...

Answer (score 0):

For a really RAD solution you can use

- fpGUI

  - https://sourceforge.net/projects/fpgui/
  - http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm
  - http://www.turbocontrol.com/embeddedfreepascal.htm
- CodeTyphon

  - http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/gallery
  - http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/codetyphon_current_status.htm
  - http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon
  - http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/layers_and_areas.htm