# providing GUI layer to embedded board

Tags: embedded-linux

I have ported uCLinux on an embedded board and want to provide it a GUI
layer.

Actually my board is consist of an ARM processor and other peripherals and
a touch screen display.

Actually this is a small embedded board which I have made .

I want to display various gui widgets like buttons , scrollbars etc . I
want to use QT for this purpose.

But I don't know how to proceed , how I can make the QT GUI layer to
interact with kernel

So , can you tell me how can I make it to talk to the uClinux kernel, I
mean how can I interface it to the kernel.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970129/displaying-an-image-on-arm-9-board

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use an embedded Linux build system. The historical one for systems based on uClinux is called uClinux-dist, but you can also use other build systems such as Buildroot. It already integrates Qt, so you'll only have to select an option, run make, and you'll have a Busybox+Qt system ready.

From the graphical side, Qt can directly use the kernel framebuffer, so as soon as your kernel has the framebuffer driver for your platform, you're ok. For the input side (keyboard, mice, touchscreen, etc.), Qt uses the Linux input subsystem, so if your input devices are supported by the kernel, Qt will be able to use them directly, with nothing additional needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LVGL](https://lvgl.io). It's easy to port and comes with many widgets.